# What order are Android permissions displayed in?

Tags: android, security, permissions, android-permissions

When a user installs an Android application, the Android system displays the list of (dangerous) permissions that the app is requesting on a warning screen, as part of the installation process, and asks the user to approve this list.

What order are the permissions displayed in, on this screen?  What's the algorithm that Android uses?  Is there some fixed order on all permissions, and Android just displays the subset the app needs in that fixed order?  If so, what is that order?  (Where could I find it in the AOSP source code?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can see how it is implemented in `frameworks/base/core/java/android/widget/AppSecurityPermissions.java`. There is enough clear code for well understanding how permissions are grouped.